# Chrome extension to block websites, track time spent on websites etc

Tags: chrome

> I need a software recommendation for **Chrome Extension** for managing my time and increasing productivity.

---

**Requirements:**

1. Block certain websites - for some limited duration (ex: social sites for 1 month of exams) / indefinitely (ex: sites I totally dislike),
2. Keep track of sites I visit - number of visits per day, the time spent on each site (per day),
3. Classify sites - I am able to classify sites as work / fun / important / project etc. ,
4. Measure my productivity by analyzing the time spent on work / entertainment etc.

**Preferences:**

1. Should not be very heavy (I have a slow internet connection).
2. Easy-to-use interface
3. Includes a reminder or something like a quick to-do list.

---

> I want an extension to manage my time spent on the internet. I know of several extensions which can be used to block websites (I already have one), and also those which track time spent on certain websites. However, I want one extension for all these tasks. Currently, I use the internet for studying, my own projects, entertainment, some internship work, SE, blogging, etc.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Is there an option to track how much time you spend idle, like when I open a tab, and stare it for 40 minutes? (no activity, no scrolling etc.)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Nanny](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nanny-for-google-chrome-t/cljcgchbnolheggdgaeclffeagnnmhno)

Blocks specified sites and allows tagging of blocked sites (categorising)

> If you just want to find how much time you spend on some site, Chrome Nanny can do it too ! Just add the domain in the White Listed URL. Such URLs are not blocked but tracked.

You can check how much time you've spent on certain whitelisted sites in the Statistics page.

[image: nanny]

The interface is dated unfortunately, but you can't have everything I guess.